# How to set arguments for savon version 2

Tags: soap, wsdl, savon

I'm reading railscast #290 that are going with savon version 1.
So I tried to replace command for version 2, but I couldn't do it.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/290-soap-with-savon?view=asciicast

I replaced the commands like these.

ver1 `client = Savon::Client.new("http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL")`

ver2 `client = Savon::Client.new(wsdl: "http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL")`

ver1 `client.wsdl.soap_actions`

ver2 `client.operations`

ver1 `client.request :web, :get_info_by_zip, body: { "USZIP" => "90210" }`

ver2 `client.call(:get_info_by_zip) # need more`

How can I set namespace `web` and body parameter `USZIP` and `90210`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this (www.webservicex.net is not very reliable though):

```
#!ruby

require 'savon'

WSDL_URL = 'http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?wsdl'

client = Savon.client(wsdl: WSDL_URL,
                      log: true, # set true to switch on logging
                      log_level: :debug,
                      pretty_print_xml: true)

zip = ARGV[0] || "10004"

response = client.call(:get_info_by_zip, message: {"USZip"=>zip})

print response
```

Comment: is their a way to get message keys dynamically example 'USZip' like listing operations

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. If I'm guessing right then the WSDL is what you want. It gives you the structure of the SOAP call.

Comment: using wsdl will get structure with the operations available. Is their a way to list the message options for each operation.

Comment: yes, SoapUI will give you the correct syntax with all mandatory and optional parameters. It uses the WSDL for that.

Comment: Not implemented, you can extend the WSDL parser if you want :-). Currently you'll get the list of operations and that's it.